# Hola, Como puedo hacer para que el en vez random.randint() me de el resultado con variables personalisadas?

Tags: python

Quiero hacer que la variable *ganador* de como resultado el numero aleatorio, pero en vez de eso me da las variables *numero 1* y *numero 2*.

```
import random

numeros = numero1, numero2 =(int(input("Selecciona un numero:")), int(input("Selecciona el segundo:")))
entrada = input("Adivina un numero del {} al {}:".format(numero1, numero2))
ganador = random.randint = ("{} {}".format(numero1, numero2))

if entrada == ganador:
    print("Felicitaciones, has acertado")
if entrada != ganador:
    print("Perdiste, Intentalo de nuevo")
    print("El numero correcto era {}".format(ganador))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `randint`

**random.randint(a, b)**

*Retorna un entero aleatorio N tal que a <= N <= b. Alias de randrange(a, b+1).*

En el código le estás pasando un string con ambos valores, en lugar de los valores por separado.

La línea correcta es:

```
ganador = random.randint(numero1, numero2)
```